# Joint Conditional Probability - Binary Pixels

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

How does one calculate the joint conditional probability?

We're making a Naive Bayes classifier for a set of black and white images, representing digits in the range $Y\in (0-9)$.

The point of using Naive Bayes is to reduce the number of required computations for $P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3|Y)$. We have been given, that without Naive bayes, the number of computations is equal to 2^3, which is the same as $n^k$ where k= number of pixels, n = their colours. With Naive Bayes it simplifies to 3 computations, due to the assumption of independence.

My question is then, how do I go about showing that that is the case using simple product and conditional rules of probability?

$P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3|Y)$, given that for every $X_i \in {0,1}$.

What is the formula for calculating this?

Comment: You need to provide more information to define your problem. It's not clear yet.

Comment: There is a standard formula for conditional probabilities, using the basic rules, as you state.  It's unclear how that wouldn't directly apply.  But are you asking how to *estimate* these probabilities from data or how to *compute* them from other information?  It's unclear what "this" refers to in "how do I go about showing this."

Comment: @whuber What is this formula for joint probabilities? I know of $P(A|B) = P(A\cap B) * B$

Comment: It looks like there are some typographical errors: it's $\Pr(A\mid B) = \Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B).$

Comment: @whuber Oh, I see. For some reason I cannot click the edit button.

But would you be able to relate this to conditional joint probability of the three pixels given Y?

Comment: There's no difference: the joint conditional probability still concerns an event $A$ conditional on an event $B.$  It doesn't matter that $A$ is defined in terms of three variables rather than one.